# Active Android memory leak? Why is registry holding onto everything I do?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, activeandroid

I am currently using Active Android for my application and have seemed to run into a problem.  I feel like this cant be right, but from what I am observing, I am getting a memory leak and I think its Active Android's fault.  Every time i do a select, either by using execute() or executeSingle(), it looks like all the rows in the table I am querying get held in the heap.

After doing some leak checking, I found that the object depth stops at com.activeandroid.Registry and is held as an mRegistry object within com.activeAnroid.Registry$InstanceHolder.

I have checked the documentation, and I see no mention of this, nor any way to clear it.  I certainly cant let it go as the leak causes my application to crash within a few hours (there are many rows which are constantly being written and read from the database).

Answer (score 0):

After some looking into the ActiveAndroid classes, I found that ActiveAndroid has a static Clearcache() method, (so simply call ActiveAndroid.clearCache()) and it will cleanup the registry.

So if you are using Active Android and run into a memory leak, please ensure you are calling ClearCache every once in a while.

Thank you!